# Angular1 filter:{field:'!!'} not working

Tags: angularjs, filter

I want the most basic of filters on my list, if a certain value is null (rather than an array) then filter it out

JSON Sample

```
{
  "runningServices": [
    {
      "servicename":"service1",
      "previousLocations": null,
      "cancelReason": null,
      "delayReason": null
    },
    {
      "servicename":"service2"
      "previousLocations": null,
      "cancelReason": null,
      "delayReason": {
         "reason":"pigeons"
      }
    },

    ]
}
```

My code (the controller binds the data to $scope.listOfServices = data.runningServices)

```
<tr ng-repeat="service in listOfServices | filter:{delayReason:'!!'}>
//stuff
</tr>
```

Without the filter, everything lists, with the filter I just get a blank screen.. also tried '!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a small filter (*nullFilter* in my example):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.listOfServices = {
    "runningServices": [
      {
        "servicename":"service1",
        "previousLocations": null,
        "cancelReason": null,
        "delayReason": null
      },
      {
        "servicename": "service2",
        "previousLocations": null,
        "cancelReason": null,
        "delayReason": {
           "reason": "pigeons"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  $scope.nullFilter = function(value){
    return value.delayReason !== null;
  };
});
```

and in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="service in listOfServices.runningServices | filter: nullFilter">
  {{service.servicename }}
</div>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pc2TkQh5qlnoF6JqfqZh?p=preview

Comment: I cant thank you enough for the effort you put into this solution. Using your example was what I needed to help me fix my issue and give me a nice intro to customer filters as well. I only needed the filter as I have incorporated the .runningServices 'extra level' into the scope in the controller. Thanks again

Comment: glad to help you :), please note that nullFilter in my answer is just a second argument for angular JS core filter (and is not a filter by its self), I updated my plunker and added customNullFilter, (which is a custom filter) and its implementation. enjoy :)